# HP Proliant DL120 G6 Memory issue

Tags: memory, hp-proliant, boot

I bought new RAM for my DL120 G6, but with it installed it does not boot. I thought it might be incompatible so I bought another batch of memory but same result.

I get no display output and no keyboard input, the fans are spinning at pre-boot rpm, no audible error codes and iLO says everything's ok.

CPU: Intel Xeon x3470

Previous RAM (if I put it in it works fine) : 4x 2GB-2Rx8-10600E DDR3

New RAM 1: 4x 4GB-2Rx4-10600R DDR3 (Lenovo)

New RAM 2: 4x 4GB-2Rx4-8500R DDR3 (Hynix)

P.S.: It will not boot with only 2 sticks installed either.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this spec](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c02027715) it's an entry level model and doesn't supports 4Gb modules. It also supports only unbuffered memory which you've had before. But now you are trying to install registered memory. Bus width also differs (x8 vs x4).

My best guess is to try 4GB-2Rx8-10600E (unbuffered, ECC) RAM module to see if it works, but that will most likely fail so I won't suggest spending money on this unless you can "try before buy".

Comment: why is it a entry model? with the x3470 cpu i got the highest one supported by this server

Comment: @TwoFish entry model platform, not the CPU.

Comment: but it says 4gb r-dimms are supported here

Comment: https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c02037017